# Finding gcd of permutations of a Number

Tags: c++, math, largenumber, greatest-common-divisor

Here is the link to the problem:

http://www.spoj.com/problems/GCD/

> Consider the decimal representation of a natural number N.
>   Find the greatest common divisor (GCD) of all numbers that can be obtained by permuting the digits in the given number. Leading zeroes are allowed.

I worked on the following approach :
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/22453

> First, if all the digits are the same, there is only one number and that is the GCD. As was pointed out before, if 3 or 9 is a factor of one permutation it will be a factor of them all. Otherwise, imagine swapping just the ones and tens digit when they are different. The GCD of these two has to divide 100a+10b+c−100a+10c+b=9(b−c) where b and c are single digits. For the GCD of all the numbers to have a factor 2, all the digits must be even. For the GCD to have a factor 4, all the digits must be 0, 4, or 8 and for 8 they must be 0 or 8. Similarly for 5 and 7. Finally, the GCD will be 27 if all the digits are 0,3,6, or 9 and 27 divides one permutation and 81 if all the digits are 0 or 9 and 81 divides one permutation. Can you prove the last assertion?

My solution:
http://ideone.com/VMUb6w

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<string>



using namespace std;

int rem(string str, int a){
    if (str.empty())
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int temp = (str[str.length() - 1] - '0') % a;
    int temp2 = 10 % a;
    str.erase(str.length() - 1);
    int temp3 = (rem(str, a)*temp2) % a;
    return (temp3 + temp) % a;
}


int gcdf(int a, int b)
{
    return b ? gcdf(b, a%b) : a;
}


int main(){
    string str;
    while (cin >> str)
    {

    size_t l = str.length();
    vector<int> digit;
    int sum = 0;
    int frequency[9];
    for (int i = 0; i<9; i++)
        frequency[i] = 0;
    int zero_sum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        if (str.at(i) != '0')
        {
            frequency[str.at(i) - '1']++;
            sum += str.at(i) - '0';
        }
        else
        {
            zero_sum++;
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        if (frequency[i])
        {
            digit.push_back(i + 1);
        }
    }
    int gcds = 0, gcd = 1;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < digit.size(); i++)
    {
        gcds = gcdf(digit[i], gcds);
    }
    if (gcdf(3, gcds) == 1)
    {
        gcd *= gcds;
    }
    if (gcds == 6)
    {
        gcd *= 2;
    }
    if ((rem(str, 81) == 0) && (gcdf(gcds, 3) == 3))
    {
        gcd *= 81;
    }
    else
    {
        if ((rem(str, 27) == 0) && (gcdf(gcds, 3) == 3))
        {
            gcd *= 27;
        }
        else
        {
            if (sum % 9 == 0)
            {
                gcd *= 9;
            }
            else
            {
                if (sum % 3 == 0)
                {
                    gcd *= 3;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if((digit.size()==1)&&(zero_sum==0))
            cout<<str;
    else            
         cout << gcd << endl;


}
return 0;
}
```

But it is giving WA.
I cannot seem to find any edge case on where it might be wrong.

Please tell me where am i wrong. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> First, if all the digits are the same, there is only one number and that is the GCD.

You don't handle this (first) case

So with your code all of `11`, `111`, `44` gives wrong answer.

> [..] 81 if all the digits are 0 or 9 and 81 divides one permutation.

It seems that your test is wrong for that:

```
if ((rem(str, 81) == 0) && (gcdf(gcds, 3) == 3))
```

Did you mean:

```
if ((rem(str, 81) == 0) && (gcdf(gcds, 9) == 9))
```

And so

You have for permutation of 3699 inconsistent results:

```
27 for 3699, 3996, 6939, 6993, 9369, 9693, 9936
81 for 3969, 6399, 9396, 9639, 9963.
```

My implementation to check (for int number) is:

```
int my_gcd(std::string str)
{
    std::sort(str.begin(), str.end());
    std::string first = str;
    int gcd = atoi(first.c_str());

    while (std::next_permutation(str.begin(), str.end())) {
        gcd = gcdf(atoi(str.c_str()), gcd);
    }
    return gcd;
}
```

Comment: I have implemented as you said.
But still i am getting wrong answer.