# how to find gcd of all permutations of a large number of order 10^250?

Tags: algorithm, math, recursion, permutation

Consider the decimal representation of a natural number N. Find the greatest common divisor (GCD) of all numbers that can be obtained by permuting the digits in the given number. Leading zeroes are allowed

I don't want the code, just the logic on how to approach the problem
http://www.spoj.com/problems/GCD/

Here is the pseudo code that I was trying:

```
if sum of digits divide by 3 then k=3
if sum of digits divide by 9 then k=9
else k=1
if all digits divide by 2 then o=2
if all digits divide by 4 then o=4
if all digits divide by 8 then o=8
if all digits divide by 5 then o=5
if all digits divide by 7 then o=7
else o=1

if all digits are same , print itself
else print o*k
```

But i am getting Wrong Answer every time.

Comment: link should not be in title :( You have to give a resume of the problem in your own question.

Comment: sorry ..my first question.

Comment: i've also seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698691/finding-gcd-of-permutations-of-a-number ... there the answer is not complete.

Comment: I think you'll want to find a way to iterate over the range of values. You'll want to use Euclid's algorithm and test for divisibility with modular arithmetic.

Comment: Consider 3699.  The gcd over all permutations is 27.  Your algorithm returns 9 (k=9, o=1).

Comment: can you guide how to proceed and solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let me think...

If for example your huge number contains the digits two and three, then one permutation ends in 23, another permutation is identical except that it ends in 32. The difference is 9. Therefore the gcd of all permutations is a factor of 9, which means it is 9, 3 or 1.

Can you go from there?

Comment: i've tried that also...any more hints about other factors 7,5 ...as 111118 is divisible by 7 but its digits are not divisible.

Comment: i want i cases my pseudo code is ignoring or is wrong with.

Comment: I can't see any justification whatsoever for your pseudo code. You'll have to start with the maths.

Answer (score 0):

To give you a stronger hint: Every common divisor of x and y is also a divisor of x-y. That's why you don't need to find all the divisors of 250 digit numbers. You find the divisors of *some* differences of such numbers.

If you have two digits 5 and 7 in your number (because that is what you asked), there is one permutation (248 digits)57 and another permutation (same 248 digits)75. The difference is 18. The gcd of all numbers divides 18.

Now it's your turn. What can you conclude if you have two digit 2 and 9 by taking one permutation ending in 29 and one ending in 92? And if you have more than two different digits, what can you conclude?

Comment: Why did you post essentially the same answer twice?

Comment: conclusion for two different digits a and b is : gcd divides 9(abs(b-a))..no idea if 3 different digits :\